# Why my dispatch action doesn't work in use effect after request?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I need help. I don't understand why my dispatch action doesn't work. I've redux store currency list and current currency.

My reducer:

```
export const currencyReducer = (
    state: typeState = initialState,
    action: TypeActionCurrency
): typeState => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.CURRENCY_FILL_LIST:
            return { ...state, list: action.payload }

        case types.CURRENCY_SET_CURRENT:
            return {
                ...state,
                current:
                    state.list.find(currency => currency._id === action.payload) ||
                    ({} as ICurrency),
            }

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

My actions:

```
export const setCurrencyList = (currencies: ICurrency[]) => ({
    type: types.CURRENCY_FILL_LIST,
    payload: currencies,
})

export const setCurrentCurrency = (_id: string) => ({
    type: types.CURRENCY_SET_CURRENT,
    payload: _id,
})
```

My useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (!list.length) {
            const fetchCurrencies = async () => {
                try {
                    const data = await $apiClient<ICurrency[]>({ url: '/currencies' })
                    dispatch(setCurrencyList(data))
                    if (!current._id) dispatch(setCurrentCurrency(data[0]._id))
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                }
            }
            fetchCurrencies()
        }
    }, [])
```

I want make request when load page and write currency list to Redux store, if we don't have current currency we write default currency from data.

There is one more strange thing, my redux extension shows that the state has changed, but when I receive it via the log or useSelector, it is empty

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tm2Gz.png)

Thanks!

Comment: you should create a loader and track by this loader when the list will be updated

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure but it should work.

```
 const [loader, setLoader] = useState(false);
    const list = useSelector(state => state.list)
    useEffect(() => {
            if (!list.length) {
                const fetchCurrencies = async () => {
                    try {
                        setLoader(true)
                        const data = await $apiClient<ICurrency[]>({ url: '/currencies' })
                        dispatch(setCurrencyList(data))
                        if (!current._id) dispatch(setCurrentCurrency(data[0]._id))
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.log(error)
                    } finally {
                       setLoader(false)
                    }
                }
                fetchCurrencies()
            }
        }, [])
      useEffect(() => {
            console.log(list);
        }, [loader])
```

Comment: My fail is I place useeffect before init Provider Redux. Thanks for your variant